# Removed PhoneGap / Cordova plugin keeps returning back to config.xml

Tags: cordova, phonegap, phonegap-cli

I have a strange issue with PhoneGap cli 8.0.0. I accidentally installed a wrong plugin with `phonegap plugin add` and removed it later with `phonegap plugin rm`. Calling `phonegap plugin list` does not list the removed plugin. The plugin definition **is not** removed from `config.xml` after the commands. If I delete it manually, within 1-2 minutes the plugin definition appears back to config.xml even I do not run any commands (except serve).

What to do?

Comment: try to remove platform android / browser and readding it again

Comment: > `phonegap remove platform browser` returns failures. It might be better to reinstall everything...

(node:10836) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): [object Object]

(node:10836) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.